# Wordpress - Imported pages appear, but lost data

Tags: php, wordpress

I exported just the pages from one WP install to another and it was successful. When I go to the pages list, it displays them all and shows parent/child relationships, but doesn't seem to be recognized anymore when using some custom code in the template. It works on the original site just fine and I compared WP versions; they're the same.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC'));

    // Get the page as an Object
    $products =  get_page_by_title('Products');

    // Filter through all pages and find Products' children
    $products_children = get_page_children($products->ID, $all_wp_pages);

    // echo what we get back from WP to the browser
    echo '<ul id="product-nav">';
    foreach($products_children as $child){
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_page_link($child->ID).'" title="'.$child->post_title.'">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($child->ID).'<span>'.$child->post_title.'</span>';
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

When I performed a `var_dump()` on `$all_wp_pages`, they aren't being displayed there either. It's as if they don't exist, but show up on the back end as expected. Finally, I tried changing one of the child page's parent, then back again in hopes that would reset it, but had the same result.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Define "back end". Do you mean WP Admin or the database?

Comment: @the_pete Sorry, yes, the WP admin is where the pages still appear to have parent/child relationships. The content is all there as well.

Comment: How did you perform the export?

Comment: @WilliamC Using Tools > Export in the Admin and then the WordPress Importer plugin to import it via Tools > Import

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried displaying just one of the posts via get_post()? I wonder if there might be an issue or conflict with the post ids/guids.

Comment: @WilliamC So I tested that out with some random pages/posts and it worked. I was able to dump all of the data from the parent and child pages. I have been tinkering with it and found that it always breaks if the key `order` has a value of `ASC`. I also added an if statement after the query is processed and it was returning true, but for some reason wasn't displaying any data. I changed the value to `DESC` and it works; just not in the preferred order. I'm not sure why it's doing this because of a simple ordering value. Especially since it works just fine on the original site.

Comment: I suppose you could query your posts by DESC order and then re-order the array outside of the query.

Another method might be to try modifying your query like this:

http://pastebin.com/7wtgzJy8

This method is new from version 4. Might be worth a try?

Comment: @WilliamC I got the same result. So yeah, I'll just get the data and resort it. Thank you for the suggestions.